# What is ratio of the intensities of these two equally loud sources?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

A 50 Hz source is perceived to be equally loud as a 1 kHz source at 20 dB
when its intensity level is 50 dB higher than the 1 kHz source. What is the ratio of
the intensities of these two equally loud sources?

Comment: Use the [equal loudness curves (phon scale)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon).

Comment: I don't think they need the Equal Loudness contours. The problem clearly states the relation between the two relations. All they have to do is just use the definition of the dB, which is itself the ratio of two values (with consistent dimensions of course).